# List some users of a Table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Hi I want to list some users from a table in my data base.

Model:

```
class listPatients {

    private $list_patients;

    function __construct() {
        $this->list_patients = array($patient);
    }
    //put your code here
    function list_patients() {

        $this->db->from('Users');
        $this->db->where('patient', 1);
        $this->db->select('id, username, Email');
        $patient[]=$this->db->get()->result();
        return $patient[];
    }
```

`

View

```
<?php echo $patient[] ?>
```

Control:

```
   public function list_patients() {
        $data["list_patients"] = $this->listPatients->list_patients();

        $this->load->view('mainview',$data);

    }
```

I want to show a list of the patients(Users with column patient = 1) and I am getting some problems can someone help

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: i get this error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: patient

Filename: views/mainview.php

Line Number: 58
 <?php echo $patient ?>
Backtrace:

File: /home/a15_web01/web/app/application/views/mainview.php
Line: 58
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/a15_web01/web/app/application/controllers/Main.php
Line: 18
Function: parse

File: /home/a15_web01/web/app/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrieving data from Db dont pass the entire result_object.  instead of passing the entire $patient(result object). store the result_object to a variable and pass it ie $patient=$patient[0]; change this line in your model

```
function list_patients() {
    $this->db->from('Users');
    $this->db->where('patient', 1);
    $this->db->select('id, username, Email');
    $patient=$this->db->get()->result();//change
    $patient = $patient[0];//
    return $patient;//
}

//controller

 public function list_patients() {
    $data["list_patients"] = $this->listPatients->list_patients();
    $this->load->view('mainview',$data);
 } 

//view in mainview.php 

foreach ($list_patients as $value) {                  
    echo $value->patient;
}
```